# Uneven columns in two-column paper format

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, two-column

I am writing a paper in two-column format.  I avoid using the `multicol` package as I deal with quite a bit of within-column figures and would rather have them float. However, I am facing a problem that I can't resolve.  The pages that contain the single-column figures as opposed to the ones which spread over the two-columns, end up having uneven columns at the end of the page.  One of the columns is always one row (line) shorter than the other.  This is, however, not true if the page just contains text or has a figure spread over both columns. 
I was wondering if anybody has ever experienced something similar or knows how to resolve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.